# How to set manager to user in Active Directory in Management console?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

How to set manager to user in Active Directory in Management console ? 
I found the Attribute Editor tab in user's Properties. But it is not resolving the other user name. Is there any other way to add manger to any user in Active Directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, by "Management console", you are talking about Active Directory Users and Computers, then it is on the 'Organization' tab, right under 'Company'.

If you mean the Exchange Management Console, then it is also on the 'Organization' tab there too, under "Office".

Comment: Thanks it worked. :)
I could do also by providing DN value to Manager attribute in Attribute Editor tab. But your way is easy.